# Any chrome extension which rotates image on a page?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions

Is there any chrome extension which rotates image on a page?
Some photo sharing sites, does not rotate vertical image automatically. 
So i need to see those images by turning my head. Is there any chrome extension which can do the job for me easily when i browse?

I have tried .picnik, but that seems too heavy lifting for my purpose.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[GooEdit](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/mldnfiglpcfdfnaephjhpgocgnmgjkhp#)

In case you need one for Firefox: [Image Zoom](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/image-zoom/)

Answer (score 2):

The extension [Flip this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flip-this/donljlliiecjcagcenoeohjmabfegkph?hl=en) allows you to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want an extension for that, and don't mind wacky behavior with *all* images on a web page, you can use the following bookmarklet script by creating a bookmark and using the script below as address:

> `javascript:(function(){for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)document.images[i].style.webkitTransform='rotate(90deg)';})()`

On SuperUser, it rotates all avatar pictures (not the logo though, as it works differently). You might need it in two variants though, `90deg` and `270deg`, since repeatedly pressing the bookmarklet won't have any effect.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually a much better Chrome Extension called [IMG Rotate](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/img-rotate/jcoonajankpbolkgbipphpmbhefkengn?hl=en) which allows you to right-click an image and just select how much you want to rotate it by.