# Rotate Chrome 90 degrees clockwise/counterclockwise

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, rotate

I've recently bought a 1920x1080 screen, the NEC EA232WMI to be exact. This monitor can easily rotate and pivot until I get it in a portrait orientation.

Sometimes when I'm browsing the interwebs I'd like to rotate my display. But I don't want to rotate my whole desktop because my icons will get rearranged, my rainmeter setup will break, my taskbar quicklaunch menus etc.

It would be great if I could just rotate the contents of Chrome using an extension but I couldn't find any. In [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/246273/any-chrome-extension-which-rotates-image-on-a-page) someone recommended an extension which rotates images; but that won't cut it.

I found this [upsidedown extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/ejmdppmmnogaandoecmdhkbcgolhfefd) which is just great... if only the dev would have realized he was on to something much more useful with this than just a prank.

So does anyone know of a proper rotate extension? Or do I have to write one myself?

Comment: you should be able to edit that extension to rotate 90 instead of 180...i'll look

Answer (score 4):

You could take a look at the [Flip This Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/flip-this/donljlliiecjcagcenoeohjmabfegkph?hl=en). It allows to rotate and flip any page (according to the description)

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to what I was asking for (which doesn't exist and I maybe will get to writing an extension myself this summer), I found a few tweaks to keep your desktop from being screwed whenever you change resolution/aspect:

- Rainmeter: I realised that by unchecking the Settings > Keep on Screen feature in all of your meters, they will stop being influenced by your screen resolution changes and thus will not be broken when you change screen size/aspect. However, this way, you might not see them at all when you're in a lower resolution (they would be off-screen).
  Rainmeter said that they will fix this auto-positioning problem in later releases.
- [Desktop Restore](http://www.midiox.com/index.htm?http://www.midiox.com/desktoprestore.htm) works for any Windows version and saves your desktop icon positions. It's so clever in fact that it allows you to save an icon layout for every resolution you are in. Then, when you switch to 1080x1920 for example, you can load your 1080x1920_layout instead of the 1920x1080_layout.
  It has no tray icons, it's just a shell extension that adds three entries to your context menu (right-click on desktop).

This pretty much solves most of my screen-rotate related issues; so now I can just flip the display via my GPU driver (ATI in my case) whenever I rotate my monitor. As a bonus, games that change your screen resolution will no longer break my Rainmeter and icon setups.

Cheers! And do post a reply in case you find a Chrome extension that rotates page content.

PS: [Screen Capture](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) is a Chrome extension by Google that allows you to take a snapshot of the whole page, not just what you can see in your scrollbarred-window.

Comment: I organize my desktop icons with the free version of `fences` - it helps to keep the icons where you want them when changing the resolution http://www.stardock.com/products/fences/