# How can I modify this script to rotate images on Facebook?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, facebook

First of all I almost know nothing about programming. I want to rotate any picture that people shared. Tried the bookmark [which is mentioned in this answer](https://superuser.com/a/296584). It only rotates 90 degrees. Then doesn’t work again

```
javascript:(function(){for(i=0;i<document.images.length;i++)document.images[i].style.webkitTransform='rotate(90deg)';})()
```

How can we manupulate this which it makes 90 degree rotate everytime I run?

I guess a possible solution get images rotation degree then check if it is 0 degree or 90 degree.

A second solution might be to keep a variable. i.e. var `rotated=true`

Is this possible? Or do you know any Chrome extention which does accomplishes a similar task?

Comment: I have tried GooEdit and img rotate . they dont work

Comment: filip this and img rotate do the rotation to other images except facebook images. I think we should modify this code